# Iframe ContentWindow Show / Hide elements based on the Iframe source

Tags: javascript, iframe

Iframe ContentWindow Show / Hide elements based on the Iframe source
Plnkr.co example code: https://plnkr.co/plunk/yv5HLC4TxB3ql8XU

I am trying to show the ‘aside’ element when the iframe source ContentWindow source is anything but the initial iframe source.
I have tried numerous methods describe in StackOverflow and none have worked for me.
In my plnkr.co example I have a main index.html page with two iframes (iframeone.html, iframetwo.html).
Iframeone.html’s content consist of a linked list to two pages (betaOne.html, betaTwo.html). From either one of these betaOne / betaTwo pages the user can return to the iframeone.html.
Iframe’s contenWindow is betaOne or betaTwo I would like the ‘aside’ element to be visible.
When the Iframe’s contentWindow is the initial ‘iframeone.html’ then I would like to hide the ‘aside’ element.

Example of my javascript:
'''
function evaluation(){
var iframesource = document.getElementById("iframeOne").src;

```
    alert('From within Document.ready.') // using this to ensure that my external js file is being accessed.
    if(iframesource.includes('iframeone.html')){
        alert('internal alert YES');
        document.getElementById('asideMenu').style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        alert('internal alert NO');
        //$("asideMenu").css('visibility') = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('asideMenu').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: Test for the URL from the page that contains the `<iframe>` like, `const iframeWindow = iframeElement.contentWindow, iframeHref = iframeWindow.location;`... so `iframeHref` is the String you're looking for.

Comment: I got it to work. While your method didnt work for me, it certainly was a useful breadcrumb. Thank you.
My Iframe:
    <iframe name="contentFrame" onLoad="evaluation();" id="contentFrame" src="body_ros.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```js
function evaluation(){

  var iframeoneContentWindow = document.getElementById('contentFrame').contentWindow;
  alert(iframeoneContentWindow.document.URL + 'External Script Alert');

  if(iframeoneContentWindow.document.URL.includes('body_ros')){
      alert('internal alert YES');
      document.getElementById('contentSide').style.display = 'none';
  }else{
      alert('internal alert NO');

      document.getElementById('contentSide').style.display = 'block';
  }

}
```